# Problems reading data from Binary store .I tried lots of solution but not working please help me

Tags: android, build, dependencies, analytics

'''Launching lib/main.dart on vivo 1907 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':onesignal_flutter:generateDebugRFile'.

> In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[10.2.
> 1, 17.3.99]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

Dependency failing: com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.16.0 -> com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@[10.2.1, 17.3.99], but fire
base-messaging version was 17.3.4.

The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
ifact with the issue.
-- Project 'app' depends on project 'onesignal_flutter' which depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@{stric
tly 17.3.4}
-- Project 'app' depends on project 'onesignal_flutter' which depends onto com.onesignal:OneSignal@{strictly 3.16.0}
-- Project 'app' depends on project 'onesignal_flutter' which depends onto com.onesignal:OneSignal@3.16.0

For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = true }" to your bu
ild.gradle file.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 51s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
'''

Comment: Have you found any solution?